# Issue in Submitting Unity App For Mac App Store?

Tags: unity-game-engine

hi I need to upload the unity app for Mac appstore, but I didn't find any proper way to upload it and unity Documentation is not helping, can anyone tell me what is the proper way to upload it

Comment: Have u been a developer of app store?

Comment: yes I am a Developer and upload apps of iOS successfully

Comment: It's almost the same, add a macOS app first, then upload your app via xcode.

Comment: I added the app done, I am making build form unity done, now I don't know how to attach or open the build in Xcode , I will upload it from Xcode if it is open in Xcode or what ever I am only missing this point

Comment: If you built the app via unity (.app has been generated), you could use Application Loader (XCode > Open Developer Tools).

Comment: I can't find application loader in Xcode 13.2

Comment: It has a new name: [Transporter](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12)

Comment: sorry to bother you but transporter is not there and I also goto more developer tools I did not find it there also, I downloaded transporter separately from App Store its is also not allow me to upload .app

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: sorry for writing urgent I get that @jps, yes its my mess

Comment: What did you mean it is not allow you to upload?

Comment: I open the transporter, it says add package and .app package is not selectable

Comment: Following [unity's docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-PortToAppleMacStore.html) to create pkg.

Comment: I followed that doc, creating Xcode project and finding .entitlement file and info file is causing the issue because I can't find it there, may be I did not making Xcode project right because there are option of swift xib and other which I don't know what to select.

Comment: @AhsanAli these files are created by yourself.

Comment: I suggest you to export as an xcode project (Select Create Xcode Project in Build Settings), then to build and upload it in xcode (just like how you build an iOS app).

Comment: thank you for help @shingo I was missing the select Xcode project in build setting part. thank you for all the help